# Iterate through each row and column of a dataset

Tags: r, dataset, rows

I'm kind of new to R, and I need to convert several datasets into one big mysql table.

What I need is to iterate each row of the dataset and get each row adding the label of the column and value of the row as well as its id into a new row.

Example: Lets say the dataset below:

```
      ID    NAME    AGE
1     2589  Joe     31
2     2590  Joseph  15
3     2591  Maria   40
```

I need to turn it into:

```
      id   question  answer
1     2589 NAME      Joe
2     2589 AGE       31
3     2590 NAME      Joseph
4     2590 AGE       15
5     2591 NAME      Maria
6     2591 AGE       40
```

I need to do this to several datasets that doesn't have the same number of columns, but the result dataset should have the same format.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This seems less than ideal if you already have the datasets in R. Are you aware there are packages for writing directly to mysql? If you really need this intermediate format, you are looking to `melt` or `stack` the data - `cbind(dat[1], stack(lapply(dat[-1],as.character)))` for instance.

Comment: I agree, it seems like a strange transformation if writing to MySQL is the goal.

Comment: Actually, I have hundreds of files in SPSS, from several different surveys, and I'm trying to use R as a intermediate to read, transform and then save into mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your table to long format using `tidyr::gather` then sort by `ID`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

txt <- "ID    NAME    AGE
1     2589  Joe     31
2     2590  Joseph  15
3     2591  Maria   40"

df <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

df %>% 
  gather(key = "question", value = "answer", -ID) %>% 
  arrange(ID)

#>     ID question answer
#> 1 2589     NAME    Joe
#> 2 2589      AGE     31
#> 3 2590     NAME Joseph
#> 4 2590      AGE     15
#> 5 2591     NAME  Maria
#> 6 2591      AGE     40
```

Created on 2018-03-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Try `tidyr::gather()`. For your example assuming a data frame `mydata`:

```
library(tidyr)
mydata %>% 
  gather(question, answer, -ID)
```